# Express insert values into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express-4

PROBLEM SOLVED. Please look below.

I'm new into Express and NodeJS, ditched Laravel and PHP.

What I want to do is to be able to add a record into MySQL database, but I am not able to connect the dots. I'm following this tutorial series :

http://eddyjs.com/bookshelf-js/

http://eddyjs.com/using-mysql-with-bookshelf-js-part-2-using-the-database/

There are two db variables, I couldn't understand how to use them.

Here's the error.

> Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
>       at Object. (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/myapp/models/User.js:5:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)

I installed all dependencies via npm, everything is ok.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "bookshelf": "^0.8.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "knex": "^0.8.6",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
```

I hold my models in models folder.

User.js

```
var db = require('./db');

var User = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users'
});

module.exports = User;
```

routes/index.js

```
router.get('/add', function(req,res,next) {
  var User = require('../models/User');
  new User({
    'name': 'Edwin',
    'pet': 'dog'
  })
      .save()
      .then(function (newUser) {
        console.log('user created!', newUser);
      });
});
```

db.js (database connection should be opened once, right? So it has to live here)

```
   var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'root',
        port    : 8889,
        database : 'databasename',
        charset  : 'utf8'
    }
});

var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I change db.js. The key is the module.exports = db; part, I guess.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'root',
        port    : 8889,
        database : 'bosluk',
        charset  : 'utf8'
    }
});

var db = require('bookshelf')(knex);

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Correct, if you don't export anything, thank including the module will not assign anything to the variable.

It's worth noting that if you want to export multiple stuff, instead of using `module.exports`, use `exports.someThing` instead, that way `someThing` will be a property of the object you assign the module to.

Also, if the module is in the same directory, there is no need for the ./ in your module require path.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the directory structure of your project, you have the routes directory next to the models directory, right?
if this is the case, you need to change the require in routes/index.js to use ../, so it will get to the right location:

```
var User = require('../models/User');
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. Now I'm getting a new error.

Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/myapp/models/User.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)